# Language localisation for buttons

Tags: html

I have this code for English pages:

```
<li><a hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en" class="button">English</a></li>
```

Can I declare hreflang for buttons?

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en" />
```

Edit: My pages are HTML5

Comment: You ask about buttons, but your example is a `link` element, which does not generate anything visible (by default). Please make it clear what you mean by “button”: what specific HTML element(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Buttons don't link to anything, so it wouldn't make sense to say that "The thing this button links to is written in the *whatever* language".

Comment: is this code incorrect? <a hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en" class="button">English</a>

Comment: @nikel — Aside from the `;` in the middle of that, that is fine. You were asking about buttons though, and that is an anchor.